# Click event stops mousemove and can't continue

Tags: javascript, html, dom, addeventlistener

I want to make 2 divs to follow cursor, but click event stops the whole mousemove event an I can't continue even if I redefine EventListener again at the end of the click event function

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function () {
    HL.style.top = `${event.clientY - 1}px`;
    VL.style.left = `${event.clientX - 1}px`;
});
```

How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `event` function parameter. You want:

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
    HL.style.top = `${event.clientY - 1}px`;
    VL.style.left = `${event.clientX - 1}px`;
});
```

Comment: It seems right, but mousemove works even without that. I tried putting the parameter, but it still stops after clicking.

Comment: You probably have a bug somewhere in code that's listening for mouseclick